# Improve SQL Server SELECT in table with many records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my SQL Server database that has around 270.000 records and I need to make my `SELECT` as fast as possible but I have no clue how to do it or what to start looking for.

This is my table `Resultado`:

```
resultadoID (PK, int)
participanteID (FK, int)
perguntaID (FK, int)
tipo (nvarchar(5))
valida (int)
```

This is my `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT 
    participanteID, tipo, 
    COUNT(valida) as validas 
FROM 
    Resultado 
WHERE 
    valida = 1 
    AND participanteID = {ID} 
GROUP BY 
    participanteID, tipo
```

This database is an online test and this table records all the answers of each participant for further consulting.

My problem is at the end of the test I have to perform this consult to give him his answers but I'm getting some problems at this last part where I can't assign him this and I'm guessing the problem is my table size.

In my tests my consult is not taking more than 1 sec but I can't measure it in all cases (e.g. slow connections or time-outs)

Comment: You can add an index on columns participanteID and valida.

Comment: go through this http://java.dzone.com/articles/6-simple-performance-tips-sql

Comment: @tvelykyy i already have the index, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT participanteID, tipo, COUNT(valida) as validas
FROM Resultado
WHERE valida = 1 AND participanteID = {ID}
GROUP BY participanteID, tipo
```

The best index for this query is on `resultado(valida, participanteId, tipo)`:

```
create index resultado_valida_partipanteId_tipo on resultado(valida, participanteId, tipo);
```

Comment: I already have an index at `participanteID` and `perguntaID`, should i remove them ?

Comment: @Terkhos . . . One composite index is optimal.  You can have multiple indexes on a table and the database engine will choose the right one(s) for the query.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i already added it, i just hope it will resolve my problem.

Comment: Last thing, should i use Clustered or Nonclustered ?

Comment: @Terkhos . . . A non-clustered index is fine.